# How to draw a Ellipse around a foreground object

Tags: opencv

working on my final year project on fall detection I have completed till background subtraction now I have to draw a ellipse around the foreground object
how to do it??
please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`cv::ellipse()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse).

[image]

You can find some examples [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an `ellipse` function just for that ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=ellipse#cv.Ellipse)). You also have the `circle` function ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=ellipse#circle)).